# CSS attributes and DIV element in blog layout?

Tags: html, css

This does not work:

```
div[newsinfo] {
background-color: blue
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

I don't want to make any mistakes before I create my blog layout in CSS.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `div[newsinfo]`? What is `newsinfo`?

Comment: In case you have a `<div class="newsinfo">` in your HTML, you'd target it via `div .newsinfo` or just `.newsinfo` in CSS. If you have a `<div id="newsinfo">` in your HTML, you'd target that with `div #newsinfo` or just `#newsinfo`.

Comment: @domsson I believe OP is talking about `data` attributes. However, we don't know because we need to see the HTML.

Comment: Oh also you need semicolons (`;`) between your lines of CSS otherwise it will complain at you.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a `;` after blue for your css syntax. Here is an example assuming you are using newsinfo as the target value itself. You could also use a class or id

```css
div[target="newsinfo"]{
background-color: blue;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div target="newsinfo">hello</div>
<div target="somethingelse">world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS attribute selectors work with standard HTML attributes, and `newsinfo` is not one of them.

You have several options:

- Use a class or id: `.newsinfo` or `#newsinfo`
- Target a standard attribute's value: `div[class="newsinfo"]`
- Use a data-attribute: `data-newsinfo="something"`

Take a look at: [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), and [Data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

Comment: You missed an option: `data` selectors. You can create any `data-` selector you want and include it in your markup. No reason to modify `DOCTYPE`, especially since HTML5.